# Why is UDF slower than pandas UDF on PySpark?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions, google-cloud-dataproc

I am taking my first steps in PySpark, and currently, I am studying UDFs and pandas UDFs. I have read several forums, and they more or less [agree](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html) that *"pandas UDFs allow vectorized operations that can increase performance up to 100x compared to row-at-a-time Python UDFs"*. Hence, pandas UDFs become an interesting subject.

For my test, I have the following dummy data:

```py
import pandas as pd
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col, pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

spark = SparkSession.builder \
                    .appName('SpacyOverPySpark') \
                    .config('spark.jars.packages', 'com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12:0.24.2') \
                    .getOrCreate()

# - Running in a GCP Dataproc Workbench Jupyter Notebook
# - Data being imported from GCP Cloud Storage
# - They're basically text paragraphs or sentences, no nulls
df = spark.read.csv("gs://my_bucket/data_sample.csv", header=True)

print("DataFrame shape: ", (df.count(), len(df.columns)))
# Gets `DataFrame shape:  (1029895, 1)`

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- posting: string (nullable = true)
```

Trying to keep it simple, I first built a udf, that splits the input text (I know there could be better implementations, based in native PySpark functions; let's put them aside during these tests):

```py
def textsplitter(texts: str) -> list:
    return texts.split()

textsplitterUDF = udf(lambda z: textsplitter(z), ArrayType(StringType()))

t1 = time.time()
df.withColumn("posting_split", textsplitterUDF(col("posting"))).show(5, truncate=10)
print(time.time()-t1)  # 0.5169014930725098 (for ~1M samples, not bad)
```

So far, so good. Now, the turn for pandas udf, using a *"from `pd.Series` to `pd.Series`"* approach. Naively here (maybe), I ran some quick speed tests over a demo `dff` (a `pandas.DataFrame` with only 10 texts) to *"pick the fastest implementation"*, and so:

```
# dff["out"] = dff["posting"].map(lambda x:x.split())
# 286 µs ± 3.79 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)

# dff["out"] = dff["posting"].apply(lambda x:x.split())
# 306 µs ± 7.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)

# dff["out"] = dff["posting"].str.split()
# 375 µs ± 7.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Knowing this, I implemented the pandas udf:

```py
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def textsplitter(texts: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    return texts.map(lambda x:x.split())

t1 = time.time()
df_dummy2.withColumn("posting_split", textsplitter(col("posting"))).show(5, truncate=10)
print(time.time()-t1)  # Who knows, I waited for ~ 1H before giving up waiting (!) ...
```

As you can see, the pandas udf does not even complete in ~1H, without triggering any error or warning. I was checking this website, and the most alike case I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61760247/16706763), [whose answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760600/16706763) (I think) explains my case too, when saying *"Unless your data is large enough such that it cannot be processed by just one node spark should not be considered"*. Still, I have some questions:

- Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61760600/16706763) explain my current case, or is there something else missing?
- How to know if my data is *"large enough"*, and how to know if several nodes are being activated in my cluster?
- The batch of information I have at the moment has ~0.5 TB in size (in general, batches that size are expected to be processed); plus my final goal is to use a custom NER model trained in [spaCy](https://spacy.io/), to extract entities from texts (this model would be wrapped in a udf / pandas udf, that similar to this case, would return *"lists of strings"*). Roughly speaking and for my use case, using a udf / pandas udf in PySpark would be the best approach?

Thank you.

Comment: [this blog](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html) shares some attractive benchmarks and examples (with explanations).

Comment: Thanks @samkart, I have read it. Anyways, I would appreciate focusing the explanation in the code purposed in my original question post: it is simple to understand and yet, **it manages to contradict the explanations and benchmarks given in your suggested post**. The idea is trying to explain why that is happening (or what could be optimized in my test code "to match the theory").

Comment: It's impossible to know why this failed without additional information so I won't address that. But incase someone else finds this, no this isn't the best way to do this. Pandas isn't any faster than vanilla python for strings. Additionally you'll pay a serialization cost to move this from spark to python and back, so the internal spark str.split should be faster in all possible cases over a udf or pandas_udf. Then when to use a udf? If the logic cannot be expressed in base spark functions.